# Bypass log-in screen after redirection MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm stuck with a problem right now. I have 4 websites each of which has a log-in screen.

Now here are the coditions before a user can log-in the these websites:

- Website #1: Username must start with `AB`
- Website #2: Username must start with `BB`
- Website #3: Username must start with `CB`
- Website #4: Username must start with `DB`

In each website, after the user supplies the correct username format and the corresponding password, he will be redirected to Account Information page.

What I want to do now is to handle this scenario:
If user is in `Website #1`, but he entered a user name beginning with `CB`, I want him to be redirected to Website #3's Account information page, and bypass the log-in page of website #3.

My current implementation redirects correctly, but to the log-in page of the website.

Even just a logical explanation on how to do it would be greatly appreciated.